# Android studio changed my document root. Can I change it back?

Tags: android-studio, bitnami

I am using the bitnami Linux install for LAMP. It set the document root at `/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs`. I also copied my development directory, `sub_crud`, to that directory, along with `phpinfo()`.

Now I installed android studio because I need the sdk emulator for some new development work. It seems that android studio silently changed the document root to `/var/www/html`.

I'd like to change it back to the bitnami standard but am afraid that will cause AVD (android virtual device manager) to no longer work. I have done this install and configure of the many, many parts at least 3 times and can't screw it up again.

Can **bitnami** and **android studio** co-exist?

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out through trial and error. First I installed a new copy of Ubuntu. Then I installed android studio, and all was AOK. Then I installed Bitnami  and all was still OK. I tested phpmyadmin to work with mysql and that was fine too. Then I installed phpStorm along with my codebase. It was fine. Then I installed php 5.6. That broke everything! The documentroot was switched from the bitnami standard to /var/www/html. The only way I knew this is by typing local host, and instead of the bitnami  default page showing it was the Ubuntu default page. Infuriating. I installed this whole system 5 times. BTW, this setup works fine on Windows.

My next and last attempt before giving up on Ubuntu completely is to wipe the hard drive and reinstall ubunutu. Then I will create a virtual box and install bitnami.  I am thinking that I could install phpStorm in the box, but I could also install it outside the box and do some remote debugging.

Or perhaps I need to just return this Linux PC and order a Windows version????